# Linux command line expansion, reuse values

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to tftp a bunch of files

```
tftp -m binary 192.168.1.2 -c put file1 target/file1
```

I've been trying to use cmd line expansion such as

```
tftp -m binary 192.168.1.2 -c put `ls *` target/`ls *`
```

but this doesn't seem to work, a ":" gets inserted after target.

Is there a quick way to expand this kind of stuff?

I want to reuse the values I got in the first expansion into the next expansion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `` `ls *` `` is **wrong.** The same intended result can be achieved by using just `*`, as in:

```
tftp -m binary 192.168.1.2 -c put * target/
```

Wildcard expansions are processed by *your shell* before running the command, so the correct way to expand `*` to a list of files is to **simply use `*`**, never `` `ls` ``.

---

Second, the *tftp* `put` command can upload multiple files, but it only accepts *a single destination directory* when doing so. You don't need to specify multiple targets, and it would not work anyway – `tftp` wouldn't know where source files end and target files begin. (As said earlier, the wildcards are expanded by your shell, so `tftp` would receive `put file1 file2 file3`, *not* `put *`.)

---

The mysterious `:` is caused by `ls` listing the contents of subdirectories. When you run `ls *`, the shell actually runs `ls file1 file2 dir1` (let's assume you have two files and a directory). Then `ls` prints "`file1`", "`file2`", followed by "`dir1: (...all files in dir1...)`".